# Trying to make SYSLOG DAEMON in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Objective:
    This daemon maintain logs at what time which text file is opened.

Step I:
    I made one empty batch file and this file would be going to log the events into one temporary log file.

Step II: 
    Associating text files with this batch file program
        i) I right clicked on one text file.
        ii) I clicked on "open with" option
        iii) Then I chose my batch file program.
    Now as I open any text file my batch file program starts running.

Step III: 
     Batch file development:
         i)  I opened the batch file which I created as empty in Step I
         ii) I wrote following batch file commands in order to above objective:

```
             @echo off
             echo %1 >>logs.txt
             time >> logs.txt
             notepad %1
             exit
```

Step IV:

i)  As I open any txt file, then this batch file runs, but the problem is as it comes to "time" command I have to manually press enter, so is there any command in batch file programming which can produce keystrokes.
ii)  Second thing which I need is as I open my text file, cmd window pops up, I want it to remain hidden from user, so that user doesn't know about logging of events.
iii) Third thing which I need is to start the notepad process in background, so that my batch file script can proceed further.

Comment: i) write `>> "logs.txt" echo(%~1` to avoid a trailing space in the log; ii) use `>> "logs.txt" time /T` or `>> "logs.txt" echo %time%` to avoid the prompt; iii) `state start "" notepad "%~1"` so that the batch file does not wait for `notepad` to finish...

Answer (score 0):

Use `%time%` (see `set /?`) on same line as %1 to have time / filename on same line. Else type `time /?` for help esp `time /t`.

Console programs have a console. Use a different technology. VBScript can start programs hidden but you would do everything in vbscript. `0` is hidden.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
msgbox FormatNumber(WshShell.Run("cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false))
```

As above but with `6` or `8`.